# can you make a Makefile to edit a c source file to print something different

Tags: makefile

I'm supposed to make a Makefile that compiles the source file year.c and after I run it, instead of printing year 2013 it should print 2014. Is there a way to do this without editing the source file?

Comment: This has nothing to do with make. I'm not sure what the question here *is* exactly but it has nothing to do with make. The question might be "how do I modify output from a program" or "how do I automate editing a C source(text) file" or something else entirely. Please try to reframe and clarify the actual question.

Comment: yeah that's what I have to do... to modify the output it has to generate... but that I have to do in Makefile...

Comment: You've missed the point. If you are asking how to transform text as a filter in a pipeline (like `sed` or something) that's a reasonable question but it has nothing to do with make. This is, presumably, some sort of assignment, correct?

Comment: Yeah it is an assigment... it says: Write a file named Makefile with the name Makefile which compile the source file year.c so that the shown year from the output will be 2014 instead of 2013

Comment: That's a somewhat nonsensical assignment since make doesn't have anything to do with any part of that really. The answer to transforming output text is a pipeline to something like `sed`. The answer to compiling a single C file to a binary with make is .... you don't need to do anything. Just the file in a directory and `make year` assuming it doesn't need custom compilation and linking flags.

Comment: well idk but I'm not allowed to modify the source file... I made it to compile it and run it but it shows 2013... and I have to make it show 2014.. somehow

Comment: and after this I have to make 2 rules: one run which when i write make run it will run the program and one clear which will delete the eventual object files and the exe that will result

Answer (score 0):

This creates an intermediate target called `c2014.c` from your `original.c` and then compiles that.

```
.PHONY: all
all: c2014

c2014.c: original.c
    sed 's/\<2013\>/2014/' $< >$@
```

If there are dependencies for `original` (libraries to link against, etc), then `c2014` should depend on those as well.

Different `sed` versions have slightly different syntax. This assumes that `\<` and >` match word boundaries.